# Performance Comparison of Linux C++ pread Function for Reading 64 Bytes from 5GB and 64MB Files

Tags: c++, linux, io, operating-system, filesystems

I'm working on a C++ project that involves reading data from files, and I want to optimize the reading process. Specifically, I'm using the pread function to read 64 bytes of data. I have two scenarios:

- Reading 64 Bytes from a 5GB File.
- Reading 64 Bytes from a 64MB File.

My goal is to determine which scenario results in faster data retrieval, or whether they achieve the same speed.

HW/SW Environment:

- Intel(R) Core i7-11700K CPU(16 logical cores, 3.60GHz, 640KB L1 Cache, 4.0MB L2 Cache and 16.0MB LLC)
- 32GB DDR4 DRAM
- 1TB Samsung NVMe SSD
- Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
- GCC 9.4.0
- FileSystem: Ext4

Here's the basic code structure I'm using for both scenarios:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int main() {
    const char* filename = "file_XX_MB";  // XX may be 5GB or 64MB
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    off_t offset = 2000000000;
    char buffer[64];
    auto st = high_resolution_clock::now();
    ssize_t bytesRead = pread(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), offset);
    auto en = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "pread time: " << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(en - st).count() << endl;
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tested the program for 10 times and calculated the average read latency. (see below)

- Reading 64 Bytes from a 5GB File: 1758.6 ns
- Reading 64 Bytes from a 64MB File: 1266.9 ns

Due to the efficient random read performance of SSD, I think `pread` latency of these two scenarios should be the same. However, the test results show that reading from a small file is faster than reading from a big one. It seems that file size can be significant factor, which makes me confused.

Any insights, performance comparisons, or explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A half a microsecond difference isn't much, there's likely to be a whole host of factors causing the difference (if there even is one). The os will be caching data, the ssd is likely doing the same

Comment: For fast access in files this big don't use normal files but use memory mapped files (mmap) specially if you need random access. 
Side notes : filename should be a std:;string (or std::string_view), don't use std::chrono::high_resolution_clock, but use std::chrono::steady_clock and stop using `using namespace`

Comment: You assume that locating a block within a file takes constant time but I don't see why this should be the case. Filesystems have to deal with fragmentation, after all. For example if you're using an ext4 filesystem, metadata is located in an [extent tree](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Extent_Tree). It is reasonable to assume a larger file has a larger tree with slightly longer search time. This assumes you're hitting the disk and not simply the [page cache](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Extent_Tree)

Comment: I don't know your use case but to me a fairer comparison would be finding data at multiple random offsets within one 5 GiB file versus 320 x 16 MiB files. I suspect then the one large file will win easily

Comment: @PepijnKramer yeah, `mmap` seems to be a better choice in big files. I need to reconsider the IO design. And Thanks for your side notes  :D

Comment: @AlanBirtles yeah... It's hard to say which factor affects the performance. Possibly file system, os, cache, internal implementation of ssd, etc.

Comment: @Homer512 Thanks for the comment. Meta data (in my view, like inode) may affect the results. Locating data in a big file may require to load more meta data (e.g., inode table and secondary inode table). This seems to be reasonable.

Comment: Regarding `mmap`: If you read a cache-cold file via `mmap` instead of `pread`, you simply replace a system call with a page fault. That won't give you anything. But if you have repeated, random access with good locality of data for caching, it will help